# Verification required

Tags: macos, iphone, itunes, ios-appstore, settings

My iPhone (5s) has randomly started to ask for verification (before you can make purchases, you must tap continue to verify). Now my problem is that with my apple account I already have a bank account linked to it which I have used on several occasions. Now it's saying my payment method has been declined, and the problem isn't with my bank account because I have tried to put in 3 other bank cards all of which been declined for no reason.

Has anyone encountered this sort of problem before. If so, do you know how to fix it? Additionally I can't remove any payment methods because in my settings there's no 'None' option to select if i don't want a payment method.

Comment: If you live outside of USA then thee is no "None" option in payments, means you have to give credit card.

Answer (score 1):

I did not have the same problem, but I also had to verify my payment details. I contacted Apple support about this problem.

They told me that I have to edit my Apple ID address via [apple.com](http://appleid.apple.com)
I made a little change in my address and saved it. Than I restored my address like it was before. When I want to download an app now, it had no problem.

It could be that you need to verify your details once again after changing your address.

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem but for me it dit.