# When I try to download an app, it says Verification Required?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

I can't update my Apps, or download Free ones. Also when I go into Settings there isn't a None option for payment options.

I tried to enter my credit card but it says "Your payment method was declined"

My iPhone model is an iPhone 5c.

Comment: The NONE payment option is only available in the USA.

Comment: So what do I do?

Comment: Provide your Credit card information. You will NOT be charged for Free apps, and for paid one you will be asked to confirm your purchase (so double protection).

Comment: I've tried that, but it says Your payment method was declined.

Comment: Which Country are you in? Some credit cards are not approved by Apple Store.

Comment: The issuing country of the card must match the country of the iTunes Store you are registering with.

Comment: ugh i have this same problem let me know if you find the solution 

Answer (score 1):

I would start with Apple support - https://getsupport.apple.com

Choose billing support in the web page or see if there is a phone number to get human support. If you exhaust your banking cards, then you might need to contact your bank to ensure your card details are correct so you enter them correctly on Apple’s site.

This thread explains how to edit AppleID information to match what your bank reports. [Verification required](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/163139/verification-required)